# regex last word in a sentence ending with punctuation (period)

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for the regex pattern, not the Java code, to match the last word in an English (or European language) sentence.  If the last word is, in this case, "hi" then I want to match "hi" and not "hi."

The regex `(\w+)\.$` will match "hi.", whereas the output should be just "hi".  What's the correct regex?

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/regex$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/regex$ java -jar dist/regex.jar 


trying
a b cd efg hi
matches:
hi


trying
a b cd efg hi.
matches:
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/regex$
```

code:

```
package regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String matchesLastWordFine = "a b cd efg hi";
        lastWord(matchesLastWordFine);
        String noMatchFound = matchesLastWordFine + ".";
        lastWord(noMatchFound);
    }

    private static void lastWord(String sentence) {
        System.out.println("\n\ntrying\n" + sentence + "\nmatches:");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
        String match = null;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            match = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }
}
```

My code is in Java, but that's neither here nor there.  I'm strictly looking for the regex, not the Java code.  (Yes, I know it's possible to strip out the last character with Java.)

What regex should I put in the pattern?

Comment: The regex you are using in your code does not have the `\.` in it. Your regex looks correct to me, the capture group will contain the word without the period.

Comment: Wait, so you want to match the last word in the line.  And if the line is ended with a period then you want to not have the period?

Comment: @Taemyr  exactly.  if there's a period, then just the last word.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflext this.

Comment: @cyon LOL, yes, I didn't understand that.  see my answer for doing what you say (although I didn't understand your point at first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookahead asserion. For example to match sentence without period:

```
[\w\s]+(?=\.)
```

and

```
[\w]+(?=\.)
```

For just last word (word before ".")

Comment: `[\w]+(?=\.)`  was the specific bit I was looking for.  I will look into what lookahead assertion means.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have the whole match be the last word you can use lookahead.

```
\w+(?=(\.))
```

This matches a set of word characters that are followed by a period, without matching the period.

If you want the last word in the line, regardless of wether the line ends on the end of a sentence or not you can use:

```
\w+(?=(\.?$))
```

Or if you want to also include ,!;: etc then

```
\w+(?=(\p{Punct}?$))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matcher.group(1)` to get the content of the first capturing group (`(\w+)` in your case). To say a little more, `matcher.group(0)` would return you the full match. So your regex is almost correct. An improvement is related to your use of `$`, which would catch the end of the line. Use this only if your sentence fill exactly the line!

Answer (score 0):

By using the $ operator you will only get a match at the end of a line. So if you have multiple sentences on one line you will not get a match in the middle one.

So you should just use:

```
(\w+)\.
```

the capture group will give the correct match.

You can see an example [here](http://regex101.com/r/lN6hF3)

Comment: that will match "hi.", while the output I want is just "hi" **without** the dot.   Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand *why* really, but this works:

```
package regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String matchesLastWordFine = "a b cd efg hi";
        lastWord(matchesLastWordFine);
        String noMatchFound = matchesLastWordFine + ".";
        lastWord(noMatchFound);
    }

    private static void lastWord(String sentence) {
        System.out.println("\n\ntrying\n" + sentence + "\nmatches:");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)");  //(\w+)\.
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
        String match = null;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            match = matcher.group();
        }
        System.out.println(match);
    }
}
```

I guess regex `\w+` will match all the words (doh).  Then the last word is what I was after.  Too simple, really, I was trying to **exclude** punctuation, but I guess regex does that automagically for you..?

Comment: It works because matcher finds all the matches.  And your while loop iterates over all these.  So once this loop is completed it points to the last word.  See answers below for using lookahead to match with conditions on what should follow the match.  Or using groups to keep only parts of the match.

Answer (score 0):

With this regular expression `(\w+)\p{Punct}` you get a group count of 1, means you get one group with punctionation at `matcher.group(0)` and one without the punctuation at `matcher.group(1)`.

To write the regular expression in Java, use: `"(\\w+)\\p{Punct}"`

To test your regular expressions online with Java (and actually a lot of other languages) see [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: I think this is likely a better path to a solution, but, no, pardon, not precisely what I was looking for.  This returns "hi." whereas I want just "hi" **without** the dot.  Pardon if that was unclear.  However, that `\p` syntax is very interesting :)

Comment: For "test1, test2 test3" it returns "test1". I expect, thats what was asked. To clarify this: `matcher.group(1)`contains the word WITHOUT punctuation (the "hi", not the "hi."). Still the "hi." can be found in `matcher.group(0)`.